# Using RxJava inside ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, rx-java, android-viewholder

I work on an image editing android app. In this app users can download assets. Because those assets are large in size, I use DownloadManager to download them. The items that the users can download are shown in a RecyclerView. What I want to do is to bind the DownloadManager download tasks to the items in the RecyclerView, so that the user sees the progress of the download. Here's the Rx wrapper I wrote for getting download progress.

```
private Observable<Integer> createDownloadProgressListener(long downloadId) {
    return Observable.create(observer -> {
        boolean downloading = true;

        while (downloading) {
            DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
            q.setFilterById(downloadId);

            Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(q);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
            int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                downloading = false;
                observer.onNext(100);
                observer.onCompleted();
            }

            final int dlProgress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100L) / bytes_total);

            observer.onNext(dlProgress);
            Log.d(TAG, "Download progress: " + dlProgress);

            cursor.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Here's how I bind to this observable in my ViewHolder's bind method:

```
private void bindEffectDownloadTask() {
        if (item.getDownloadRefId() != null && baseActivity.rxDownloadManager.getDownloadProgressListener(item.getDownloadRefId()) != null) {  baseActivity.rxDownloadManager.getDownloadProgressListener(item.getDownloadRefId())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnSubscribe(() -> item.setDownloading(true))
                    .doOnTerminate(() -> item.setDownloading(false))
                    .subscribe(progress ->
                        updateDownloadProgress(progress),
                    error -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error in download task: " + error.getMessage());
                    },
                    () -> {
                        downloadedState();
                    });
        }
    }
```

My problem is that `updateDownloadProgress` (where I set progress of a custom circle progress view) updates not only the current ViewHolder, but others as well. How can I ensure only the current ViewHolder is updated? Or if this approach is completely wrong, what are the best practices for dealing with asynchronous dataflow in RecyclerView items? Maybe should I emit download progress and object id from a BehaviorSubject, subscribe to that in my activity and find the items to be updated in the adapter and update them with the progress?

**EDIT**

the `updateDownloadProgress` method:

```
void updateDownloadProgress(int progress) {
  downloadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  downloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  downloadProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
}
```

Comment: `Maybe should I emit download progress and object id from a BehaviorSubject, subscribe to that in my activity and find the items to be updated in the adapter and update them with the progress?` sounds like the best approach to me

Comment: Please show the code of the `updateDownloadProgress()` method.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Thanks, I still can't see what's wrong.  When is `bindEffectDownloadTask` called? When are the downloads started? Could you include the whole class that contains `bindEffectDownloadTask` and `updateDownloadProgress`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTag ang getTag so that only current ViewHolder will be updated